# What is the plural of "+1"?

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe, irregular-plurals

What is the best plural of "+1" in casual American English writing?

Possible ideas I've considered include:

- `+1s`
- `+1's`

Comment: this is a duplicate. use the search.

Comment: The main sense of +1 is the operation, 'add one', which can't have a plural. If you mean the numeral [positive one], it has a plural when used 'as a word'. Italics and the apostrophe would be used, so _+1_'s,  to distinguish it from + 1s meaning + one second.

Comment: How many increments are you talking about?

Comment: What is the context of the question? We are just speculating without it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Isn't it already plural? :) *Tom **plus-oned** Dick yesterday, so it's no surprise if Dick **plus-ones** Harry today. Tom and Dick **plus-one** folks all the time, but Harry **isn't plus-oning** them back no matter how much they beg him to.* it's completely regular! So the singular is *he/she/it plus-ones*, the plural is *we/you/they plus-one*, the past and past participle are both *plus-oned*, and the gerund/participle is *plus-oning*.

Comment: @tchrist Apparently, unnatural verbifications were not unknown in '45: '... And my dear we're still goodbye-ing'. Sounds like they're at the sales./ All the best.